# extract hour from a string _ unclear format

Tags: python, regex

this question maybe is duplicated but I didn't find any exact solution for this. I have this type of string that includes date and time.

```
"check_in": "10/25/2019 14:30"
```

I need to extract an hour from it but this is not always a valid format. I tried this pattern so far but it includes the ":" character.

> \d+?(:)
>
> (\d+:)
>
> (\d+)*:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't always the best way to deal with strings representing dates, especially if you can't rely on the input format to be consistent. Use a specialized parser instead:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("10/25/2019 14:30").hour
14
>>> parser.parse("10/25/2019 2:30 PM").hour
14
>>> parser.parse("2019-10-25T143000").hour
14
```

The module `dateutil` isn't in the standard library but is well worth the trouble of downloading.

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(?=:)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8C7Js/1)

You don't need match the `:`, but need check it. So use [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=:)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is what is wrong with your regexes:

- `\d+?(:)` - finds number and column (`14:`) and puts the column into a group
- `(\d+:)` - finds number and column (`14:`) and puts all of it into a group
- `(\d+)*:` - finds (optionally, because of `*`) number and column (`14:`) and puts the number into a group

So, the last one could work:

```
>>> match = re.search(r'(\d+)*:', "10/25/2019 14:30")
>>> match.group(0)  # whole result
'14:'
>>> match.group(1)  # just the number
'14'
```

But then again, it would give wrong result (instead of breaking) on something like "time: 14:30", making it difficult to debug the error later. What you want is to use a more strict search, e.g. matching the whole string and labelling all groups:

```
>>> regex = r'(?P<month>\d\d)/(?P<day>\d\d)/(?P<year>\d{4}) (?P<hour>\d\d):(?P<minute>\d\d)'

>>> re.search(regex, "10/25/2019 14:30").group('hour')
'14'
```

Another, easier and even safer way is to use strptime:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("10/25/2019 14:30", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 25, 14, 30)
```

Now you have the complete datetime object and you can extract the `.hour` if you want.